# Allow users to select a time zone and use it during MySQL SET time_zone

Tags: php, mysql, html, timezone

I am trying to implement a time zone option on a web application. I want to use SET time_zone and it works fine. Where can I find a complete `<select>` list that has all the time_zone options available for the user to select from.
Thanks

EDIT: I would like to use the 'US/Central' format and not '+10:00'

Answer (score 0):

You can find that list at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html where it's explained how time zone settings are dependent on what your OS is supporting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a proper answer to your question but you can give it a try. Visit this [link](http://service-kl.com/code/tz_demo/). It's my demo when I was trying to get timezones by country. Maybe, you can adapt that code to your needs.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot.....might I advice that UTC at GMT are not always the same....UTC never changes while GMT is subject to daylight savings

Comment: @thearchitect - INCORRECT.. Note: Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is the same all year around There is no Summer Time  / Daylight Saving Time. So it's not subject of DST. http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time, http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx . Also, check 'GMT' timezone in PHP and you can see that PHP doesn't observe DST for 'GMT' timezone. UTC is widely accepted term, GMT is used in Europe (mostly in UK).